# Ruby/Rails CSV parsing, invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, utf-8

I am trying to parse a CSV file generated from an Excel spreadsheet.

Here is my code

```
require 'csv'
file = File.open("input_file")
csv = CSV.parse(file)
```

But I get this error

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I think the error is because Excel encodes the file into `ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1)` and not in `UTF-8`

Can someone help me with a workaround for this issue, please

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best solution is to have excel encode in utf-8

Comment: In case you need to support various encodings and detect at import, Charlock Holmes worked great for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12234195/1343535

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to tell Ruby that the file is in ISO-8859-1. Change your file open line to this:

```
file=File.open("input_file", "r:ISO-8859-1")
```

The second argument tells Ruby to open read only with the encoding ISO-8859-1.

Comment: This was giving me fits too, and your solution is working so far for me!  Thanks!

Comment: worked like a champ. I was doing an `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 oldfilename > newfilename` before i found this answer.

Comment: @jnunn: So glad I could help! Ruby encodings are harry things, and not that easy to deal with.

Comment: if you're here and using 'roo' gem, here the docs: https://github.com/roo-rb/roo#csv-support says you can send it as a symbol: `s = Roo::CSV.new("mycsv.csv", csv_options: {encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1})`

Answer (score 35):

Specify the encoding with **`encoding`** option:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|
  ...
end
```

Comment: I prefer declaring keyword arguments explicitly +1 for `encoding:`

Answer (score 11):

You can supply source encoding straight in the file mode parameter:

```
CSV.foreach( "file.csv", "r:windows-1250" ) do |row|
   <your code>
end
```

Comment: This worked in Ruby 2.1.5 but you have to do `encoding: 'iso-8859-1'` instead of `"r:windows-1250"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one (or few) file, so when its not needed to automatically declare encoding on whatever file you get from input, and you have the contents of this file visible in plaintext (txt, csv etc) separated with i.e. semicolon, you can create new file with `.csv` extension manually, and paste the contents of your file there, then parse the contents like usual.

Keep in mind, that this is a workaround, but in need of parsing in linux only one big excel file, converted to some flavour of csv, it spares time on experimenting with all those fancy encodings

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in utf-8, unless for some reason you need to save it differently in which case you may specify the encoded set while reading the file

Answer (score 0):

add second argument `"r:ISO-8859-1"`  as `File.open("input_file","r:ISO-8859-1" )`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was just using google spreadsheets and then downloading as a CSV. That was the easiest solution.

Then I came across this gem

https://github.com/singlebrook/utf8-cleaner

Now I don't need to worry about this issue at all. Hope this helps!