# How to handle arbitrary uploaded file encodings and convert them to UTF-8 in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a standard form generated using Rails `form_for` and the `accept-charset` is present. However the browser never converts the uploaded files (non UTF-8) to UTF-8.

How to let users upload a file with an arbitrary encoding and the Rails server detect and convert it to UTF-8?

If I know the encoding I would easily read it using the `force_encoding` function then use `File.encode "utf-8"`, but how to detect the encoding in the first place?

This is how I move the uploaded file to its final destination:

```
require 'securerandom'
filename = Rails.root.join(uploads_dir, "#{SecureRandom.hex}_#{uploaded_io.original_filename}").to_s
File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [charlock_holmes gem](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) which depends on the great [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) to smartly detect the correct encoding (and language). I also tried [rchardet](https://github.com/jmhodges/rchardet) but it didn't work for me. FYI there is also [Ensure-encoding](https://github.com/Manfred/Ensure-encoding) but I didn't try it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234046/rails-3-check-csv-file-encoding-before-import) helped me.