# identifying problematic row of data giving mass import error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, activerecord-import

I am using activerecord-import to bulk insert a bunch of data in a .csv file into my rails app.  Unfortunately, I am getting an error when I call import on my model.

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)
```

I know the problem is that I have a string with weird characters somewhere in the 1000+ rows of data that I am importing, but I can't figure out which row is the problem.

Does activerecord-import have any error handling built in that I could use to figure out which row/row(s) were problematic (e.g. some option I could set when calling import function on my model)?  As far as I can tell the answer is no.

Alternatively, can I write some code that would check the array that I am passing into activerecord-import to determine which rows have strings that are invalid in UTF-8?

Comment: Maybe this old answer helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380113/ruby-rails-csv-parsing-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the data, it is only possible to guess. Most likely, you have a character combination that is not UTF-8 valid.

You should be able to check your file with

```
iconv -f utf8 <filename>
```