# Ruby `CSV.read` error invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-csv

First of all This is not a duplicate of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380113/ruby-rails-csv-parsing-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8) here
.I have a csv file encoded in `Shift-JIS`
this is my script to parse the file

```
require 'csv'
str1 = '社員番号'
str2 = 'メールアドレス'
str1.force_encoding("Shift_JIS").encode!
str2.force_encoding("Shift_JIS").encode!
file=File.open("SyainInfo.csv", "r:Shift_JIS")
csv = CSV.read(file, headers: true)
p csv[str1]
p csv [str2]
```

but even after specifying enconding, I am getting `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)` . Any thoughts? My ruby is 2.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your encoding doesn't look right:

```
'社員番号'.force_encoding("Shift_JIS").encode!
#=> "\x{E7A4}\xBE\x{E593}\xA1\x{E795}\xAA\x{E58F}\xB7"
```

`force_encoding` takes the bytes from `str1` and interprets them as Shift JIS, whereas you probably want to *convert* the string to Shift JIS:

```
'社員番号'.encode('Shift_JIS')
#=> "\x{8ED0}\x{88F5}\x{94D4}\x{8D86}"
```

Next, you can pass a filename to `CSV.read`, so instead of:

```
file = File.open(filename)
CSV.read(file)
```

You can just write:

```
CSV.read(filename)
```

That said, you could either work with Shift JIS encoded strings:

```
require 'csv'
str1 = '社員番号'.encode("Shift_JIS")
str2 = 'メールアドレス'.encode("Shift_JIS")
csv = CSV.read('SyainInfo.csv', encoding: 'Shift_JIS', headers: true)
csv[str1]
csv[str2]
```

Or – and that's what I would do – you could work with UTF-8 strings by specifying a second encoding:

```
require 'csv'
str1 = '社員番号'
str2 = 'メールアドレス'
csv = CSV.read('SyainInfo.csv', encoding: 'Shift_JIS:UTF-8', headers: true)
csv[str1]
csv[str2]
```

`encoding: 'Shift_JIS:UTF-8'` instructs `CSV` to read Shift JIS data and transcode it to UTF-8. It's equivalent to passing `'r:Shift_JIS:UTF-8'` to `File.open`

Comment: many thanks for your help sir , but when I tried your solution I am getting 'in `gets': "\xFB\xFC" from Shift_JIS to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`

Comment: @TonyVincent where does that error come from? I don't see a `gets` in your code.

Comment: Thats from rub's csv class `usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1807:in gets...`

Comment: @TonyVincent can you upload your `SyainInfo.csv` somewhere? (or a sample file with the very same encoding)

Comment: but i don't know why `csv = CSV.read('SyainInfo.csv', encoding: 'Shift_JIS:UTF-8', headers: true)` throws `Shift_JIS to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`

Comment: Me neither. The file could be corrupt. Hard to say without seeing it ;-)

Comment: The Encoding module defines conversions from one encoding to another, so e.g. it knows how to convert `社` from Shift_JIS to UTF-8. An UndefinedConversionError means that it found a character that it doesn't know how to convert from the source encoding to the destination encoding. That usually means that either 1. The source string's encoding isn't what you think it is, or 2. The source string has some characters that are invalid in the source encoding, which probably indicates it was produced by some software that isn't very rigorous about encoding.

Comment: FWIW, `String#encode`'s [`:invalid`, `:undef`, and `:replace` options](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-encode) let you specify how it should handle characters it can't convert. It's a shame the CSV module doesn't have the same options.